# How to turn off text wrapping?

Tags: html, word-wrap

I have question how to turn off text wrapping? I want to text on the left side will be the same as the text at the right side. I mean that text on the left side won't wrap. Please help me. Here is my code:

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(220, 0, 0), rgb(0, 0, 220));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover
}

.right {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: none;
  width: 20vw;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 20vw;
  border-radius: 3vw;
  float: right;
}

.left {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: none;
  width: 20vw;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 20vw;
  border-radius: 3vw;
  word-break: ;
}

.right:hover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vw;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}

.left:hover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vw;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}

h1 {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 20vw;
  margin-top: 0%;
  font-size: 2vw;
  margin-left: 2vw;
}

.right h1 {
  margin-left: 22vw;
}

.left h1 {}

img {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  border-radius: 3vw;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.right img {
  float: left;
}

.left img {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="left"> <img src="https://www.stockvault.net/data/2009/10/25/111266/preview16.jpg">
    <h1>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="right"> <img src="https://www.stockvault.net/data/2009/10/25/111266/preview16.jpg">
    <h1>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

I tried float:left and using margins and a lot more thing but I don't have any idea how to make this
I tried float:left and using margins and a lot more thing but I don't have any idea how to make this

Comment: You have a CSS rule called word-wrap `word-wrap: normal |  break-word | initial l inherit ;`

Comment: that didn't work. Do you know something different?